# angular error not sure why its happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, kendo-ui

- i am new to js and anguar 2
- i am getting below error when I move the three dots in the grid.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing whole code in the fiddle and relevant code below.

  ```
        this.sportsData.lockColumn(laptop);
  ```

```or-tag-here
TypeError: Cannot read property 'locked' of undefined
    at init.reorderColumn (kendo.all.min.js:49)
    at init.lockColumn (kendo.all.min.js:49)
    at SwimmingDocuments.lockKGridColumns (ball-bat.ts:863)
    at SwimmingDocuments.collectUserDraggedColumns (ball-bat.ts:847)
    at HTMLDocument.eval (ball-bat.ts:811)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-2.2.3.js:4737)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery-2.2.3.js:4549)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:236)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.umd.js:6233)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:235)


  gym(remote, running): void {
    if (remote.length <= 0) {
      return;
    }
    this.sportsData = $('#' + running).data("kendoGrid");
    let jump = $('#' + running + ' .k-grid-header > div > table > thead > tr:first-child > th');
    let high = jump.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < high; i++) {
      let laptop = jump.eq(i).attr('data-field');
      let bed = typeof laptop;
      if (bed == "string" && laptop != undefined) {
        if (($.inArray(laptop, remote) !== -1 && jump.eq(i).css('display') != 'none') || laptop == 'lockSetColumn' || laptop == 'contextRow') {
          this.sportsData.lockColumn(laptop);
        } else {
          this.sportsData.unlockColumn(laptop);
        }

      }
    }
```

Comment: Does you code accessing any property 'locked' in view or js?

Comment: in the provided code the part where 'locked' is referenced is missing.

Comment: Where is the property "locked"? Inside the "unlockColumn" function? Show us.

Answer (score 0):

This is more a suggestion.

Had today this exact error on another grid method, reorderColumn(i, column), and found your question while looking for an answer.

My problem was that passed i was outside the max column index, e.g. passed i=3 for a grid with 2 columns.

In your case error is thrown either on lockColumn or unlockColum. Would suggest to put a js breakpoint on these lines and see if laptop is a valid grid column. A valid grid column would have to be an object with properties like field, title, and so on.